# When was the last Great Conjunction on Winter Solstice?

Tags: conjunction

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_conjunction) Great Conjunction page only lists the years 1206-2398 and in those 1192 years there is no Great Conjunction landing on the Winter Solstice.

When was the last Winter Solstice Great Conjunction and when will the next one be? I want to know how rare this one is.